# Primefaces TabView by a model - remove model associated with tab on close

Tags: java, ajax, jsf, primefaces, tabview

I'm using Primefaces (version 3.0.1) `p:tabView` component, which displays dynamic number of tabs backed by a list in a model. Tabs inside TabView are closable. I'd like to remove list element associated with a tab by close event.

Here is my view:

```
<p:tabView id="tabView" var="iterator" value="#{bean.list}">
    <p:ajax event="tabClose"
        listener="#{bean.removeElement(iterator)}" process="@this" />

        <p:tab id="tab" closable="true">
            <h:outputText value="#{iterator.text}" />
        </p:tab>
</p:tabView>
```

My bean handler:

```
public void removeElement(Element e) {
    this.list.remove(e);
}
```

`Element e` is null in this case

I've also tried to use `p:collector` inside `p:ajax` element. There is [example](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/tabviewClosable.jsf) at primefaces.org showcase. According to it my event handler should look like

```
public void removeElement(TabCloseEvent event) {
    // ...
}
```

But I don't know how can I get associated with tab list element.

All answers will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`public void removeElement(TabCloseEvent event)` should be used, imo.

According to [TabCloseEvent](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces/source/browse/primefaces/trunk/src/main/java/org/primefaces/event/TabCloseEvent.java) it has a method `getData()`. This should give you access to your model class. Disclaimer: I haven't used TabView the way you do yet, but it works this way for Primeface's Tree component (i.e. selection of a node). Could you post back your findings?

Comment: Hm, thanks, I check it. I couldn't find any documentation about `getData()` method